# How to fix unrecognized selector issue in AdMob implementation?

Tags: ios, ios7, admob

I have following problem:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have linked all required frameworks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was missing -ObjC flag  in Other Linker flags

> Go to **Project settings** *>* **Build Settings** And set *-ObjC* in **Other Linker Flags**.

[image: XCode project settings]