# DFPInterstitial: unrecognized selector gad_MD5String

Tags: ios, google-dfp

I'm adding the **Google DFPInterstitial** support to my IOS app and

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
```

That line throw an Exception : **[__NSCFString gad_MD5String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14f5ac30**

I don't know what to do.
The GoogleAdMob sdk has been updated, Analytics is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else comes here and neither the existing answer (i.e., use an old version of admob) or the comment (use the newest version) solve the problem, the solution may be simply add the linker flag -ObjC to the project/target settings (from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079060/381233).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what I did to solve that was:

1. Get an older version for the SDK
2. Go to the Build Settings
3. Write in other linker flags -force_load libGoogleAdMobAds.a in Debug and Release.