# Admob errors with Spritekit

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, admob, sprite-kit

Trying to integrate Admob with Spritekit.

I am getting an uncaught exception

**"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADSlot state]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17ef1440'"**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this link.

[How to fix unrecognized selector issue in AdMob implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079059/how-to-fix-unrecognized-selector-issue-in-admob-implementation)

I was missing the -objC flag.

Annoying!! (Wasted my full day!)